# C# GattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync: TX size

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Sending data over BLE to my device using [GattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic.writevalueasync) I cannot transmit more than 24 bytes at once even if my UWP windows app negociated a 244 bytes MTU with my device during connection.

Writing 244 bytes into my device's FIFO characterstic results in 10 writes of 24 bytes each + 4 bytes in the last write.

How can I force a single write of 244 bytes as my device supports it and has a characteristic of this size ?

- Looked at official API documentation for options.
- Looked for alternative/other functions to write

```
private static readonly int FIFO_SIZE = 244;
...
if (txSize >= FIFO_SIZE)
{
  /* Copy chunk of data to send */
  Array.ConstrainedCopy(data, i * FIFO_SIZE, bytesToSend, 0, FIFO_SIZE);
  i++;

  /* Convert to IBuffer type */
  dataToSend = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(bytesToSend);

  /* Write FIFO characteristic (244 bytes) >> observed physically 10 writes 0f 24 bytes + 1 write of 4 bytes */
  status = await fifo.WriteValueAsync(dataToSend, GattWriteOption.WriteWithoutResponse);

  if (status != GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FIFO write error !");
  }
    txSize -= FIFO_SIZE;
  } 
...
```

I expect to be able to send data buffers of 244 bytes as this is supported by the negotiated MTU and the characteristic is big enough to receive 244 bytes.

**Is there a way to force the characteristic write size or will Windows always use the conservative value of 24 bytes ?**

In the opposite direction, my device writes packets of 244 bytes and these are received by my Windows application as a single packet!

Comment: How do you know Windows and the device have negotiated a MTU of 244 bytes?

Comment: @Codo My device (a [u-blox NINA-B1 module](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/nina-b1-u-connect)) reports the negociated MTU size with an AT unsollicited result code when a connection is established.

Comment: See  [AT commands manual](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/u-connect-ATCommands-Manual_%28UBX-14044127%29.pdf) section _5.10 Peer connected +UUDPC_ . I could test it with nRF Connect from a smartphone with different MTU sizes.
 When Windows connects I get:
+UUDPC:1,1,4,D43B04CBDB52p,**244**
Which means 247 bytes ATT MTU --> 244 bytes GAP data length.

Comment: 247 is the maximum MTU size supported by my device and [Windows automatically negotiate the highest possible MTU] (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d16679dc-48ed-4e29-83b1-cf281987f7dc/uwpblegattmtubluetooth-low-energy-ble-mtu-negotiations-issue):
_Effectively, this means that Windows will always request 525, then negotiate down to the maximum the device supports_